# Changing the format of Get-Process timestamp

Tags: powershell, format

I am running the following Powershell command to get the Start Time for a tomcat service:

```
Get-Process Tomcat8 | Select-Object starttime | Out-File c:\uptime.txt
```

It outputs the following response, which is great

```
StartTime
---------
19/11/2015 08:40:25
```

I wondered if it would be possible to pipe the date/time stamp to a file in a different format? And only that single line.

Ideally, the format I'd like would be

```
'nov,18,2015,14:50:00'
```

Which I believe would be: mmmm,DD,yyyy,hh:mm:ss

Is there a way I can do this all on one line?

Comment: `Get-Process Tomcat8|% starttime|% tostring "\'MMM,dd,yyyy,hh:mm:ss\'" ([cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture)|Out-File c:\uptime.txt`

Comment: Perfect, thank you. I was trying to do StartTime.toString

Comment: `% tostring` ? Is that an alias ?

Comment: @sodawillow `%` is an alias to `ForEach-Object`, `tostring` is a method name.

Comment: If understood it well, it's equivalent to `Get-Process Tomcat8 | % { $_.StartTime } |% { $_.ToString("\'MMM,dd,yyyy,hh:mm:ss\'", [cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture) } | Out-File c:\uptime.txt`. Didn't know you could ommit so much in PowerShell, thank you very much.